# Método de clase que manipula evento TextChange en c#

Tags: c#, eventos

mi consulta es la siguiente: Tengo un método de una clase que recibe un `textbox` como parámetro y le cambia algunas propiedades como Fondo y tamaño, pero no se como hacer para modificar el evento `text_change`

A)

```
public class CambiarColor
{

    public void CambiaTextbox( TextBox tx)
    {
        tx.Background = Brushes.Blue;

        //Ahora quiero que cuando el texto cambie cambie el color  de letras 
        //Ej: azul,rojo,verde,azul,rojo... al teclear *texto destacado* 
    }

}
```

O sea, normalmente lo hacia así

B)

```
 private void TxtEjemplo_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (TxtEjemplo.Text.Length > 0) {/*cambio color*/ }
     else if (TxtEjemplo.Text.Length > 3) { /*cambio color*/}
 }
```

pero lo que quiero saber es si al pasarlo por parámetro dentro de ese método en esa clase en `A)` puede hacer lo mismo que hacia en `B)` y manipular ese evento .

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, tu pregunta estaria mejor formulada si compartes el código que tienes hasta el momento para poder ayudarte mejor y tener un punto desde el que partir. Puedes usar este enlace para editar tu pregunta [edit].

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! A que te referis con modificar el evento text_change? queres agregar una funcion al mismo? o que cosa queres hacer?

Comment: Para cuando llamas al método CambiarColor el textbox ya ha cambiado de valor y ha disparado el evento? O es que quieres suscribir el control textbox que mandas como parámetro a un evento genérico, así todos los controles de ese tipo que envíes utilizaran el mismo.

Comment: Anteriormente colocaba 30 textbox y uno por uno en el evento Text_Change colocaba una condición para cambiar el color, ahora lo que quiero hacer es llamar a los textbox que necesite y automáticamente esos textbox tengan el mismo evento TextChange(osea la mismas condiciones) reutilizar el código , no se si es posible y no estoy encontrando como hacerlo .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es primero crear el manejador del evento de la siguiente manera:

```
private void Textboxes_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t= (TextBox)sender;
    if (t.Text.Length > 0) {/*cambio color*/ }
    else if (t.Text.Length > 3) { /*cambio color*/}
}
```

Al manejador le llega el objeto que ha lanzado el evento en la variable `sender`, con lo que puedes usarlo para generalizar cualquier `Textbox`.

Luego lo único que debes hacer en tu método `CambiarColor` es suscribirte al evento:

```
public void CambiaTextbox(TextBox tx)
{
    tx.Background = Brushes.Blue;
    tx.TextChanged += Textboxes_TextChanged;
}
```

De esta manera cada vez que llamas a `CambiarColor`, te suscribes al evento. Debes tener cuidado ya que si llamas mas de una vez a `CambiaTextbox` para el mismo `TextBox`, te suscribiras varias veces al evento con lo que se llamaría varias veces a `Textboxes_TextChanged` cuando el texto cambie. Pero supongo que llamas a `CambiaTextbox` una vez nada mas cuando creas el `TextBox`, con lo que creo que no deberías tener problemas.

Answer (score 0):

no dices si estás usando WPF o windows forms, pero en las dos puedes suscribir el evento de cambio a un evento:

```
<TextBox  TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler">
</TextBox>
```